# CSS / HTML How do I add a 'title' to my menu bar?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm using a menu bar, which I will link the code to below. I was wondering if there was a way which I could add the name of my website to the very left of the menu bar, like a title, thanks.

Menu bar code:

```
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Undefined</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Undefined</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Undefined</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Undefined</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Undefined</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Undefined</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Undefined</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Undefined</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>  
<style type="text/css" >

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);

*, *:before, *:after{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

/*| Navigation |*/

nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  z-index: 111
}
  nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    display: inline-table;
  }
    nav ul li{
      float: left;
      -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }

    nav ul li:hover{background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);}
    nav ul li:hover > ul{display: block;}
    nav ul li{
      float: left;
      -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
      nav ul li a{
        display: block; 
        padding: 30px 20px;
        color: #222; 
        font-size: .9em;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
      nav ul ul{
        display: none;
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute; 
        top: 100%;
        box-shadow: -3px 3px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
      }
        nav ul ul li{float: none; position: relative;}
          nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 30px; 
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
          }
          nav ul ul ul {
            position: absolute; 
            left: 100%; 
            top:0;
          } 
</style>
```

Comment: Please provide relevant codes along with your question. Codes in external links might expire thus making this thread useless in the long run.

Comment: Have a look at how bootstrap does it. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

How about something like adding the title as a new list item?

```
<li class="title">Title</li>

.title {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  color: #222;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.title:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

The hover here is used to simply override your existing hover, causing the title to not change it's background colour.

I've created a fiddle of this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/Lbsx2gf0/).

**Update**

For getting the title to stick to the left, simply move it one level up in the DOM, so it's outside of the `<ul>`, but inside `<nav>`. Then add `float: left;` to your `title` class:

```
.title {
  float: left;
}
```

By moving the title outside of your `<ul>`, you actually won't need any of the hover override any more, so you can get rid of:

```
.title:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I've created a new fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/m2w16577/1/) (note that I've removed some of the undefined links in order to showcase the behaviour with a small window).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but is there a way of pushing it to the very left?

Comment: There sure is! I've updated my answer to show how to do this :)